# Menu background fixed width with CSS/JQuery menu doesnt work

Tags: css

I have problem with my background jquery menu .

I can't make it with a fixed width which is the same as background image . It goes with width with the text typed .
and button repeat it if the text is longer , its like width, no-repeat doesnt work when I type them . 
Can anyone help me please .

you can see the menu here http://www.bgoffice-online.com/tab

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It just doesn't work the way you think it should work. ;-) You have an image that's a fixed width. You could theoretically scale it with element attributes, but that's not what you want because your rounded corners, etc. will not look how you want.

If you want to use these exact images for these tabs, I recommend doing a web search for "CSS tabs sliding doors". The sliding doors technique was the old standby for this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

shadetabs li a css this properties into this

```
.shadetabs li a {
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
z-index: 50;
padding: 15px 0px;
margin-right: 3px;
margin-left: 0px;
color: #2D2B2B;
background: url(1.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 210px;
display: inline-block;
}
```